# Alembic fails to upgrade database because of missing VARCHAR length and cannot correct

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I ran

```
flask db upgrade
```

and received the error

```
VARCHAR requires a length on dialect mysql
```

So I corrected my `VARCHAR` by adding the length like this

```
username = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(256))
```

Then I ran

```
flask db migrate
```

and get the error

```
Target database is not up to date.
```

Now I'm stuck. I'm in a catch-22. I cannot migrate to the database with `VARCHAR(256)` because my database is not up-to-date. I cannot make my database up-to-date because the migration for `VARCHAR` (without the '256') is not valid.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the last migration file you generated (make sure the last file you got matches migration version in alembic db table). Then modify your model and generate a new migration.